# GCP bucket recursive file/folder deletion

Tags: python, algorithm, file, recursion, google-cloud-platform

I have a GCP bucket folder structure:

`reporting/year/month/day/[list of csv's]`.

I'm trying to run a cleanup process where CSV files older than 4 days are deleted, this is easy enough iteratively but I'd also like to delete any empty folders as I go. I've been trying to write a recursive solution as I think it suits this problem. When I make the call to fetch the blobs from GCP, they return as a list of strings representing the full path e.g.
`reporting/2022/12/08/2022-12-08-csv.csv`, and I'm struggling to navigate the structure recursively for deletion. I'm wondering if a recursive approach is best for this or there might be something more appropriate (attempting using Python).

I've written an iterative solution that doesn't delete empty folders. I've researched traversing a list of file-path strings recursively.

Comment: The empty folders you want to delete are `day` ?

Comment: @MazlumTosun it would be day, then that could result in month being deleted if it left month empty, then year etc.

Comment: Folders do not exist, so you do not delete to worry about deleting them. If you see something like a folder, double-check that what type of object it is. Some software creates objects with special metadata to fake folder names. Cloud Storage can auto-delete objects: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/lifecycle

Answer (score 0):

GCP Cloud storage stores blobs in flatspace (ie. there are no directories to navigate). [image: GCP Cloud storage filesystem]

The directories shown in [GCP console are zero-byte objects used to visualise  catalogs](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/folders).

There's no need to do recursive filesystem traversing, you can lookup all blobs with given prefix and remove them

```
def delete_reports_for_day(day: datetime, bucket: str):
    prefix = f'reporting/{day.strftime("%Y/%m/%d")}'
    blobs = storage_client.list_blobs(bucket_name, prefix=prefix)
    for blob in blobs:
        blob.delete()
```

As the `directory` files for days have the same name as prefix list_blobs they will be deleted with that call.

Comment: That's very helpful thanks! What about the case when a month has no further files due to the deletion of a day? I would want to delete in that case

Comment: In that case you would need check if there is only one file under the prefix `reporting/{year}/{month}`, which would be the `directory` file. Sadly, the [GCP API can only lookup the prefix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58137826/regex-with-prefix-parameter-for-list-blobs-with-prefix).